# Extracting numbers from an expression

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-manipulation

I evaluate an integral like this:

```
C = 109.593;
pdf3a = 5.86017;
pdf3b = -0.0279324;
Integrate[C * u *(u+pdf3b) * E^(-(pdf3a) * u), {u, 0, x}]
```

And the output is of this form:

[image]

How can I extract the constants here, like  18.7014 and save it to a variable? Or is there a way to make mathemathica output data more suitable for that?

Thanks!

**Edit: Question has been answered by corey in comments**

Comment: Please post not just images but also code in textual form.

Comment: The variables are just defined as numbers(that were pre-calculated), so I didn't think it would add anything. My bad.

Comment: You should get a warning running this code as `C` is a built-in symbol; it's safest to use lowercase letters for user defined names.

Comment: `Cases[expr, _Real, Infinity]`

Comment: Prefer `Cases[q, _?NumberQ, -1]` for this particular kind of task. `_?NumberQ` is more robust than `_Real`.

Comment: `Cases[expr, Times[a_?NumberQ, x^_.] :> a, Infinity]` for just the numbers in a product with x, or x^2.